# Is that possible to transfer rating from my old account to a new one on SO?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

How can I do this? I have migrated from one Gmail account to another and now have two accounts. It would be nice to sum ratings from both and migrate to one of accounts that is newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email team@stackoverflow.com with both account IDs and the OpenID used to create the account and they'll merge them for you.